# How to find average in Access?

Tags: ms-access, average, ms-access-2013

I am trying out Access for the first time and I am trying to figure out how to really harness the amazing power of Access.

With that, I want to find the average quantity of each item but do not know how to do that. I set up 2 tables. One is the list of items (sand, water, etc.) then set up a relationship to another table that put out the quantities and price.

Below, Query 1 I set up and sorted it (I don't know why it isn't alphabetical even though I sorted ascending, but thats not why I'm here). So could someone help me try and figure out how to average each items amounts like in Query 2? Ultimately, I really just want the query to find the MaxAve and the MinAve and just show those 2 like in Query 3 below.

```
Query 1                Query 2                  Query 3
fldName     fldNum     fldName      fldAve      fldName       fldAve    
Sand        4          Sand         4           Sand          4
Sand        4          Water        3.8         Computer      3.35
Water       3.7        Soda         3.43        
Water       4          Computer     3.35         
Water       3.7        Phone        3.43         
Soda        3.7        Pencil       3.75         
Soda        3.3        
Soda        3.3        
Computer    3.7        
Computer    3          
Phone       3          
Phone       3.3        
Phone       4          
Pencil      4          
Pencil      4          
Pencil      3
```

Like I said I'm very new to Access and I am just trying things out. If you recommend setting up the query a different way Im open to anything really. The more I learn the better.

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/training/queries-ii-limit-your-data-and-calculate-values-RZ001126949.aspx?section=14

Comment: So all I have to do is click the Totals Button then Total by Ave? Then how to I just make the highest and lowest Ave appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the average for each fieldname, just do this in a query:

```
SELECT FieldName, Avg(FieldNum) as AvgQty
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY FieldName
ORDER BY FieldName
```

This will also sort the fieldname column for you.

**EDIT**:
I think you can do what you asked for in your comment, but you will need a separate query based on the one above.  You'll need a UNION query to do it.  Something like:

```
SELECT Top 1 FieldName, AvgQty
FROM Query1
ORDER BY AvgQty ASC

UNION ALL

SELECT Top 1 FieldName, AvgQty
FROM Query1
ORDER BY AvgQty DESC
```

I'm doing that off the top of my head, so it may not be perfect.

As for formatting the field, do a google on "VBA Format Number" and you should be able to find some examples.  I think it might make the above query look something like:

```
SELECT Top 1 FieldName, Format(AvgQty, "##.#") as AvgQty1
FROM Query1
ORDER BY AvgQty ASC

UNION ALL

SELECT Top 1 FieldName, Format(AvgQty, "##.#") as AvgQty1
FROM Query1
ORDER BY AvgQty DESC
```

Comment: This is almost perfect. Now that it is sorted by Averages, can we format it so that it doesn't say "3.433333333333333...". Also, Is it possible to filter it so that it only shows the Max and Min?